# Binding a RadioButton group with their associated data

Tags: wpf, tags, radio-button

I have a group of RadioButtons created in XAML generated by binding to a collection of objects in the code-behind.

I am looking for a clean way of mapping between the RadioButton that has been selected and the object that it relates to (in this case the PaletteSwatch object).

The PaletteSwatch.color field is used in a separate RadioButton style definition (not listed here).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**CS Model Class**

```
public class PaletteSwatch
{

    private string colorField;

    public string color
    {
        return colorField;
    }
    ...
}
```

**CS Window Class**

```
...
private ObservableCollection<PaletteSwatch> mDefaultPalette = new ObservableCollection<PaletteSwatch>();

public ObservableCollection<PaletteSwatch> PaletteDefault
{
    get
    {
         return mDefaultPalette;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=mainWindow, Path=PaletteDefault}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource swatchTemplate}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                 <UniformGrid Columns="7"/>
             </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>

...

<DataTemplate x:Key="swatchTemplate">
     <RadioButton GroupName="filterColorThemes" Click="RadioButton_Click"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer for those that might be wondering...

Basically you need to add the tag field on the RadioButton:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="filterColorThemes" Click="RadioButton_Click" Tag="{Binding}"/>
```

The {Binding} tag refers to an element in the list, in my case the PaletteSwatch object.

Then in the CS file:

```
    private void RadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
        PaletteSwatch ps = rb.Tag;

        ...

    }
```